# How to login to gdata in GWT application deployed on GAE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, gdata-api

I want to use the Google account login to retrieve the informations to be used for Google's gdata api so that when I start the application deployed on Google App Engine the user is asked for its login and I can then use this information on the server side to specify the credentials for Google Calendar login (through gdata api). How can I do that? I tried using Client login but it seems that there's no way to get password information from che Client object on the server side...

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use OAuth to get access to a Google account's calendar. This article should help you: [Using OAuth with the Google Data APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/oauth.html).